# Could length of code word obtained by adaptive arithmetic coding be more, than by using ordinary arithmetic coding?

Tags: information-theory, cryptography, coding-theory

I've generated random sequence 'YeYYLez!' and calculated code word by arithmetic coding $\gamma = 00110111$. After that I calculated code word by *adaptive* arithmetic coding and got code word $\gamma = 0001000100101$. Which is longer, than in case of ordinary arithmetic coding. Is it ordinary situation or I have a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Adaptive arithmetic coding is something which adapts the probabilities used in the arithmetic encoding process depending on which symbols have already been seen. As I don't have the information of which regions are used for which letters, how the initial probability table looks or how their probabilities are assigned it is quite hard to verify. But in a general setting it is possible to get a longer code word before the adaptation has managed to model the statistics of the source well. As the sequence is quite short, this might not have happened yet.